# what is the best program to view process memory map?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need to view image/heap/malloc()/stack and other resources used by process. I knew about Memory Validator but it lacks some of features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the tools from Sys Internals.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027

Namely RamMap and VMMap.

If you can state what features you're looking for, then it would help to provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Some options:**

[Process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)?

[Windbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009)?

Visual Studio?

What exactly are you looking to view?

Comment: thanks i tryed it all, i need more detail view, with addresses, ownership and sizes.